# На своем ли месте стоят тире? Выполняют ли они экспрессивную роль?

Tags: пунктуация

Он больше слушал ее, а потом однажды повторил засевшие в памяти слова… Ох, досталось ему от отца! Ремнем досталось, когда он про небо выдал: «Оно синее — всегда синее! — только иной раз не видно».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, все хорошо.

> § 174. Посредством тире выделяются: 
>   1. Предложения и слова, вставляемые в середину предложения с целью пояснения или дополнения его, в тех случаях, когда выделение скобками (см. § 188) может ослабить связь между вставкой и основным предложением, например: 
>   ...Как вдруг – о чудо! о позор! – заговорил оракул вздор. 
>   Крылов
>   ([Тире](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire))

Comment: Нестандартное предложение, так как на месте вставки стояла запятая (перед "только"), а  в приведенных примерах не было  никакого знака.

Comment: @Jasmin, По-моему, восклицательный знак "поглотил" запятую.

Comment: Я нашла похожую конструкцию у Лопатина, там запятая остается перед вставкой.

Comment: У того же Лопатина в примерах такой структы (запятая между 1-й и 2-й частью основного предложения) при отсутствии знака в конце вставки (знака, относящегося к самой вставке) запятая стоит перед вторым тире — это ее место. Перенос запятой — ничем не обоснованное нововведение Лопатина. У Розенталя этого нет.

Comment: "2) перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура **первой** части основного предложения" (Розенталь, http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125,2#pp125). Первой, а не второй!

Comment: 1) Я уже говорила, что конструкция нестандартная, так как  в правилах у классиков наших она не разбирается.. 2) Лопатин приводит только пример решения для вставки с вопросительным знаком, кстати весьма логичный.  А как еще быть, перенести и после вопросительного знака запятую поставить? 3) Ваша идея о поглощении запятой - это ВАШЕ НОВОВВЕДЕНИЕ (запятые в этой теме не поглощаются), и вы таким оформлением фактически уравняли два разных варианта (с запятой и без знаков). 4) Еще вариант - это поискать подобные конструкции у классиков в литературе  - как они решали эту задачу, но это не так просто.

Answer (score 1):

**Оно синее, — всегда синее! — только иной раз не видно.**

Сравнить: Оно синее, только иной раз не видно. **Запятая не переносится, а остаётся перед вставкой.**

Пример из ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128

Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, — **живы ли, здоровы ли они?** — как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах (А. Т.).

Comment: См. комментарии к моему ответу.